# String split from a CSV - Java

Tags: java, regex, split

I am having a small problem, I hope you can help.

I am reading a CSV in java, in which one of the column has string as follows:

a. "123345"

b. "12345 - 67890"

I want to split this like(Split it into two separate columns):

a. "123345", ""

b. "12345","67890"

Now, when I am using Java's default split function, it splits the string as follows:

a. "123345,"

b. "12345,67890" (Which is basically a string)

Any idea how can I achieve this? I have wasted my 3 hours on this. Hope any one can help.

Code as follows:

```
while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null)
{
      main = line.split("\\,"); //splitting the CSV using ","

    //I know that column # 13 is the column where I can find digits like "123-123" etc..
 therefore I have hard coded it.


if (main[12].contains("-"))
    {
    temp = main[12].split("-");
    //At this point, when I print temp, it still shows me a string.
    //What I have to do is to write them to the csv file. 
    E.g: ["86409, 3567"] <--Problem here!
    }
    else
    {
    //do nothing
    }
}
 after this, i will write the main[] array to the file.
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you're currently using to split the string?

Comment: see the code above. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: you can replace all '-' by ','. Use `main[12].replaceAll("-", ",");`

Comment: I tried that before.. and the result was the same...

Comment: @Natalia Getting this result: "78217,5320" which is a single string, won't be recognized as two different...

Comment: @user4618280 sorry, in that case, could you please explain what are you trying to get? Do you want to update initial csv?

Comment: I have a csv. I just want to split the 13th column into two separate columns. Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if java.util.StringTokenizer helps

Example:

StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(inputString, ";")

Manual: [StringTokenizer docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)